# Who is the Zhang with whom Hunter Biden allegedly made a deal?

Tags: united-states

According to [media reports](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2023/jun/23/white-house-mum-about-hunter-bidens-whatsapp-messa/), Hunter Biden wrote a WhatsApp message in 2017 saying:

> “And, Z, if I get a call or text from anyone involved in this other
> than you, Zhang, or the chairman, I will make certain that between the
> man sitting next to me and every person he knows and my ability to
> forever hold a grudge that you will regret not following my
> direction.”

Who's the Zhang with whom Hunter is writing? What is his full name and what company does he work for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two Chinese persons with the similar sounding "Zhang" name that Hunter Biden purportedly had business dealings with - CEFC Executive Director Jianjun Zang and Bo Zhang of Harves Century Group - and he could be referring to either one of them.

As per a *New York Post* report - [Why Hunter Biden angrily threatened his Chinese business associate](https://nypost.com/2023/06/23/why-hunter-biden-threatened-his-chinese-business-associate/) *(June 23, 2023)*:

> The exchange implies that Hunter was concerned he would be shut out of a lucrative opportunity with CEFC chairman Ye Jianming, in which — according to IRS supervisory agent Grant Shapley — millions of dollars were at stake. CEFC was at the forefront of Chinese President Xi Jinping’s Belt and Road Initiative, and Ye Jianming earned the nickname “Belt and Road billionaire” for his success.
>
> ... Jianming and CEFC **Executive Director Jianjun Zang, also known as “Director Zang,” had first met Hunter in December 2015**, according to schedules on his laptop.

Another report from *BlazeMedia* - [Hunter Biden, former Joe Biden adviser invested in Chinese company with ties to Communist Party, NBA China: Leaked emails](https://www.theblaze.com/news/hunter-biden-chinese-business-china) *(January 23, 2022)* says:

> A new report claimed that Hunter Biden and a former aide to Joe Biden invested in a Chinese company with ties to the Chinese Communist Party ... Person reportedly wrote an email to Hunter in July 2015, which invited him to travel to China the following month to meet his business partner — Bo Zhang.
>
> *"Bo Zhang and his family would host us. They are a great family with great respect and relationships in China,"* Person allegedly wrote to Hunter in an email. *"Bo graduated from American Univ and is in his late 20’s, and his parents own Harves Century Group of Shenyang - which is a top tier private Chinese real estate development firm."* ... *"They are very private, and wouldn’t tell anyone about you coming. Bo's father-in-law is actually the Governor of Hainan (Chinese Hawaii), which he doesn’t advertise at all."*
>
> Fox Business noted:
>
> It does not appear that Biden was able to make the China trip during the specific week that Person pitched in the email, but multiple emails reviewed by Fox Business show that **Person and Zhang met with Biden and Schwerin in Washington on multiple occasions** and emailed back-and-forth coordinating potential Harves-related business deals. In one 2016 email, Biden calls Zhang his "good friend and business colleague." ...

Answer (score 6):

'Zhang' appears to be a reference to Zang Jianjun, who was executive director of CEFC Energy - according to both the [NYPost](https://nypost.com/2023/06/23/why-hunter-biden-threatened-his-chinese-business-associate/) and the [Heritage Foundation's Oversight Project](https://twitter.com/OversightPR/status/1672053540661997568). Texts from Biden referring to Zang as 'Zhang' in 2017 were also revealed [last year](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-11365389/Photos-Hunter-Bidens-Chinese-business-partner-toasting-Vladimir-Putin.html).

Zang was also one of the individuals for which records of any communications [were requested](https://oversight.house.gov/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/2023-02-08-Letter-R.H.-Biden.pdf) from Hunter Biden by the House Oversight Committee in February 2023.